# Container/Item pattern without `friend`

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns

I have a class `Container` containing objects of type `Item`. They are different classes, and especially they have no common base class (e.g. a `Container` does not itself have a `Container`).:

```
class Container
{
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get { /* ... */ } }
}

class Item
{
    public Container Container { get { /* ... */ } }
}
```

I’d like to enforce that each `Item` needs to have exactly one `Container`, and I’d like to make sure there never can be an inconsistent situation such that e.g. `i.Container.Items.Contains(i)` returns false.

This could be done by e.g. adding a method `Container.AddItem` that sets the `Item`’s `Container` property accordingly or by having a `Item.SetContainer` method that takes care of `Container.Items`.

Example:

```
class Item
{
    private Container container;
    public Container Container
    {
       get
       {
          return container;
       }
       set
       {
           if (container != null)
               container.Items.Remove(this);
           container = value;
           if (value != null)
               value.Items.Add(this);
       }
    }
}
```

This could be easily done with the concept of a “friend”, but I’m using C# that does not have friends, and thus this example code won’t compile. However, it of course would compile if `Container.Items` had a public setter, but this again would allow inconsistencies: A “user” of the classes would need to know not to use the setter of `Container.Items`, but `Item.Container` instead.

After searching for quite some time, I feel there is no way to enforce this restriction that seems to be so trivial. (Using `internal` might be a work-around, but no solution.)

Is there an elegant way to enforce this one-container-per-item rule without the concept of “friend”?

Comment: Do you want to only allow Container to have access to Item.Container or what is your problem?

Comment: Can't you just pass the container in the constructor?

Comment: @hansmaad: I’d like to avoid inconsistent situations like `i.Container == c` and `!c.Items.Contains(i)`. So, yes, one solution (that is not possible without friends) is that only `Container` has _write_ access to `Item.Container`

Comment: @AndyBursh: It must be possible to change an `Item`s `Container`.

Comment: @Martin OK, so pass it in the constructor and add a setter which checks for nulls?

Comment: @AndyBursh: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extract this to a separated service that has the only resposnsibility to track Container<->Item associoations. I think this is a very flexible solution.

```
class Container<T>
{
    private IItemAssociations associations;
    public Container(IItemAssociations a)
    {
        this.associations = a;
    }

    public void Add(T i)
    {
        if (!associations.IsAddedToAContainer(i))
        {
            DoAdd(i);
            associations.AddAssociation(this, i);
        }
        else
            HandleAlreadyAdded(i);
    }
}
```

You can have a static constructor method that injects a global association object or use some other injection mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

`internal` would be a fine solution here since container and item are inextricably linked, they're going to be part of the same assembly.

**That said, this is a code smell.**

Items should generally not know if they belong in a container, let alone being restrained to only one container. This is a coupling nightmare since items will then inevitably go back to their container to look for other items, tightening that relation. Then you get into "how do I inform this item that the peer it cared about has suddenly left the container?" Which makes the container then care about which items care about what other items and on down.

Comment: Maybe it is a code smell. Consider `System.Windows.Forms.Control`: It has a `Controls` and a `Parent` property. This is somewhat similar, although it is the same class, and not two different classes.

Comment: @Martin - That's why I said code smell rather than anti-pattern. It can certainly be the cleanest way to accomplish a task, especially `location` sort of containers rather than `parent` sort of things. But I'd still avoid it if possible. As soon as a child knows about its parent, it's no longer a child but a peer.

Comment: I think this is an interesting aspect.